# array of lists in r

Tags: arrays, r, dictionary

Suppose if I want to have 10 element array each element is a list/map. I am doing this:

```
x = array(list(), 10)
x[1][[ "a" ]] = 1
Warning message:
In x[1][["a"]] = 1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>
```

Is this the right approach? I want each element of the array to be a map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're calling an "array" is usually just called a list in R.  You're getting tripped up by the difference between `[` and `[[` for lists.  See the section "Recursive (list-like) objects" in `help("[")`.

```
x[[1]][["a"]] <- 1
```

UPDATE:
Note that the solution above creates a list of named vectors.  In other words, something like

```
x[[1]][["a"]] <- 1
x[[1]][["b"]] <- 1:2
```

won't work because you can't assign multiple values to one element of a vector.  If you want to be able to assign a vector to a name, you can use a list of lists.

```
x[[1]] <- as.list(x[[1]])
x[[1]][["b"]] <- 1:2
```

Comment: The way the OP is creating the array, it really is an array with each element a list. The problem is that that list in `x[1]` doesn't have names so `x[1][[ "a" ]]` returns NULL but we're trying to assign a length 1 vector to a `length(0)` index. It works if you do `x[1][[ 1 ]]`, but as you say, much better if the OP works directly with a list not an array.

Answer (score 6):

If you *really* want to do this, then, because the elements of the lists in each element of the array do not have names, you can't index by a character vector. In your example, there is no `x[1][[ "a" ]]`:

```
> x[1][[ "a" ]]
NULL
```

If there are no names then you need to index by a numeric:

```
> x[1][[ 1 ]] <- 1
[1] 1
```

It would seem more logical to have a list though than an array:

```
> y <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
> y
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL
....
```

Comment: `array(list(), 10)` creates a list with a dim attribute, so it's very similar to your list.

Comment: @Joshua Yep, it creates an array list hybrid - R thinks it really is an array (`is.array(x)` is `TRUE`). I think the list is neater.

Comment: I don't remember exactly how `is.array` works, but `?is.array` suggests it just looks for a dim attribute with positive length.