# Store array of lists

Tags: arrays, r, list, data-structures

Is there a way to store lists (in my case of identical structure) in an array?

I saw some questions with very [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706208/array-of-lists-in-r) titles, but the accepted answer does not work me. Here is a very basic example:

```
list1 <- list(x = "x1", y = "y1")
list2 <- list(x = "x2", y = "y2")
```

And I want to do something like this (which I know is wrong and does not work)

```
lists <- c(list1, list2)
```

So that when by `lists[[1]]` I get `list1` (with the code above I get only its first element)

Ideally I would like to have `n` lists and add them to the array of lists in a loop. Is this possible in R?

Comment: And how do I do in a loop? I tried appending lists to an empty list, but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a list of lists:

```
lists <- list(list1, list2)
lists[[1]]
# $x
# [1] "x1"
# 
# $y
# [1] "y1"
```

If you really had many variables named `list1`, `list2`, ..., then you can save yourself some typing by using `mget` to build a list of all of them using their names:

```
lists <- mget(paste0("list", 1:2))
lists[[1]]
# $x
# [1] "x1"
# 
# $y
# [1] "y1"
```